# Ubuntu 15.10 on Acer E5-511will not restart on it's own

Tags: 15.10, acer

I am using Ubuntu 15.10 on Acer E5-511will and not restart on it's own. When I try restart/reboot it hangs at the Ubuntu log off/restart exit screen. What could be causing this?

Comment: Well, operating systems shouldn't shut down on their own. What exactly do you mean?

Comment: I could be confused about the process but I thought that when I selected restart after installing something it should restart without me having to force restart it by holding down the power button and then hitting hit again to power back up.